# dynamic dataTable and sortBy not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces and dataTable (lazy mode) and i need generate definition of dataTables on fly / in code. I'm able to build dataTable, columns, labels, values, ... but sorting not working.

I tried:

```
column.setSortBy("name"); // where name is name of property/column
column.setSortBy("#{row['name']}"); // where row is map and name is name of property/column - this is what im using in XML version and it working very well
column.setSortBy(ef.createValueExpression(context, "#{row['name']}", Object.class));
```

DataTable looks like with disabled sorting (no arrows at labels)...

When i have definition in XML then everything works fine (it's not about lazyDataModel or anything else in model layer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
   FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();

   ValueExpression valueExpression = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), "#{row['name']}", String.class);

   column.setValueExpression("sortBy", valueExpression);
```

where I used `String.class` because i supposed that "#{row['name']}" evaluates to an instance of the class `String`.

Comment: setValueExpression is the solution! thanks! final working version is `column.setValueExpression("sortBy", ef.createValueExpression(context, "#{name}", Object.class));` (expression must be changed to this, dont know why, but it works)